# Xamarin Forms CollectionView doesn't have KeyboardDismissMode property

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to hide keyboard on scroll on iOS.
If i'm using `ListView`, i can create `ListViewRenderer` for iOS and set `Control.KeyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive;` and its works fine.

But how to achieve the same result with `CollectionView`? There is no `KeyboardDismissMode` property in `CollectionViewRenderer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is `UICollectionView` in `Control.Subviews[0]` and `UICollectionVIew` has property `KeyboardDismissMode`.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<GroupableItemsView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                var uiCollectionView = Control.Subviews[0] as UICollectionView;
                uiCollectionView.KeyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive;
            }
        }
```